# Access View current result count in Twig?

Tags: views, 8

I need to theme the result count of a view. I am using the one provided by views in the Header of the view.

Currently, it says:

"Showing 1-10 of 200 results."

What I need to do is wrap the numbers in a span with classes to style them, so it is like:

"Showing **1**-**10** of **200** results."

and the bolded numbers are slightly larger and a different color, due to the styling.

I can't find these variables in twig or in the view preprocess, however. Is there a way to get them?

Comment: Can you use the `[view:total-rows]` token instead? Or Maybe `$view->total_rows` if in preprocess?

Comment: Oh, duh. I can just put HTML in the view header in the UI instead of twig.